# CassandraTemplate.execute Batch statements help needed in Spring

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, datastax

I am having difficult time in finding a sample program that uses the execute of batch statement as argument for org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate;

Basically I am trying to do multiple insert as a batch.

```
CqlTemplate cqltemplate = new CqlTemplate(session);
cqltemplate.execute(Batch arg0);
```

How does it all come together? Also batch has issues in dealing with inserting multiple records to any unknown table (not linked to entity class). My project requires a method to do multiple insert for a given table and hashmap of key and values (row data) - which does not have an equivalent POJO Class. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: I looked around in the web how to create a Batch statement and pass it as argument inside the execute method-none available in Spring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to work it out. Thank you for the guidance. Sorry for posting it late:

```
Insert insert1 = QueryBuilder.insert...
Batch batch = QueryBuilder.batch(insert1);
Insert insert2 = QueryBuilder.insert...
batch.add(insert2);

CassandraOperations cassandraOperations = new CassandraTemplate(session);
WriteOptions options = new WriteOptions();
options.setTtl(60);
options.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
options.setRetryPolicy(RetryPolicy.DOWNGRADING_CONSISTENCY);
cassandraOperations.execute(batch.toString(), options);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/cassandra/core/CqlOperations.html#execute%28com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Batch%29) you need to create an object of `class com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Batch`.
You can create with `com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder` `batch` method. CQLTemplate should not be created in the code, it should be injected in the configuration:

```
CQLTemplate cqlTemplate=new CQLTemplate();
yourServiceBean.setCQLTemplate(cqlTemplate);
```

And in your service/dao it would be something like:

```
Batch batch=QueryBuilder.batch (...)
cqlTemplate.execute(batch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. However batch has issues in dealing with inserting multiple records to any unknown table (not linked to entity class). My project requires a method to do multiple insert for a given table and hashmap of key and values (row data) - which does not have an equivalent POJO Class.

Comment: You should add these details to your question

Comment: A brief sample: `QueryBuilder.batch(new SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM ..."), ...)`